# active record class throws 'method_missing' when assigning object value to a declared binary attribute

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I'm using Active Record outside of rails and I have two AR classes similar to below:

```
class Building < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :rooms
   serialize :current_room, Room
```

and

```
class Room < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :building
```

I had originally migrated the database tables to have the current_room column be declared as a `:room` instead of a `:binary`, which worked, but made my db schema unusable due to the unknown type, and potentially would make my implementation non database independent. (using sqlite3, haven't tried another yet)

When I changed the table column type to `:binary` from `:room`, I started getting a "undefined method" error when attempting to change the current_room variable as I navigate the building from room to room. The error looks like this in irb, where d is a building object:

```
irb(main):006:0> d.current_room = d.rooms.first
NoMethodError: undefined method `gsub' for #<Room:0x1f6c260>
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activemodel-3.1.1/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:385:in `method_missing'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:60:in `method_missing'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:24:in `binary_to_string'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/column.rb:84:in `type_cast'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:89:in `field_changed?'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:63:in `write_attribute'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/write.rb:14:in `current_room='
    from (irb):6
    from C:/Ruby192/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

I presume it is because the object attribute isn't treating it like a Room object, which is understandable, but I thought the serialize method solved that issue. `d.current_room.class` and `d.rooms.first.class` both return Room as the object class, as well. Is there a way to have this work properly without overwriting the assignment methods?

Comment: It occurred to me immediately after posting that serialize is meant for text column types, and when I tried that, it worked. It still seems counter-intuitive though. If I can just serialize things in text, why would I ever use a binary?

Comment: Just FYI - if this is the answer to your question, then you can (and are encouraged) to type it up as the answer for the next person that runs into this problem, and finds your question. You can accept your own answer after 24 hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Serialize is intended for string column types, not binaries. When the column type is changed to string, everything works appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer specifically regarding your error message. I usually find that if I carefully read error messages it will usually tell me exactly what is wrong. So in this case...

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `gsub' for #<Room:0x1f6c260>
```

It's saying that `gsub` is not defined for `Room`. So basically, your code at some point is trying to do something like...

```
room_instance.gsub('something', 'else')
```

So I don't think it's a problem with binary vs string. I'd look at your code and search for `gsub` to see exactly where the problem is. Also, `gsub` is usually called on strings.

Comment: Yes, this is a problem but I think it was an extraneous one caused by trying to do something in an inappropriate way. I checked my code and I don't call gsub anywhere on my own. It is probably being called in the `binary_to_string` which is referenced in the third line of the error response.